# iOS Call animateWithDuration inside dispatch_async

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I've call an web API to get the result. After getting response I want to remove "visualIndicatorView" (UIView) with indication using animation function. Indication and View come to hidden state but not smoothly.

**Here is my code:**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: { () -> Void in
         self.activityIndicator.hidden = true
         self.visualIndicatorView.hidden = true
         self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}) { (completed:Bool) -> Void in
}
```

Comment: No any issue in this code. Please add hole code so i can find easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hidden` is not an animatable property. Try setting `alpha` to `0`:

```
self.visualIndicatorView.alpha = 0.0
self.activityIndicator.alpha = 0.0
```